# Image link not working on email

Tags: html, css

I have a working page can be viewable in browser.This page comes from a raw file (psd) and converted to html.However when sending through email, image links not working...How do you solve this?

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Eblast-WAE-Preorder</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 </head>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="width: 700px; margin: auto;">
   <!-- Save for Web Slices (Eblast-WAE-Preorder.psd) -->
   <table id="Table_01" width="700" height="1151" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="14">
        <a href="http://i.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_01.jpg" width="700" height="680" alt=""></a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="14">
        <img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_02.jpg" width="700" height="12" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_03.jpg" width="51" height="123" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="11">
        <a href="https://docs.google.com/d/1kSIyCanxKq-cI1xjJ4WgbKAkaESljmGDmKXnX0XFN9w/viewform"  target="_blank"><img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_04.jpg" width="598" height="38" alt=""></a></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_05.jpg" width="51" height="123" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="11">
        <img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_06.jpg" width="598" height="85" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="14">
        <a href="http://i.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Pre-Order-Ticket-Info.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_07.jpg" width="700" height="271" alt=""></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="14">
        <a href="http://i.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_08.jpg" width="700" height="15" alt=""></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        <a href="http://i.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_09.jpg" width="456" height="49" alt=""></a></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <a href="https://i.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_10.jpg" width="26" height="49" alt=""></a></td>
    <td>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdp" target="_blank"><img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_11.jpg" width="34" height="35" alt=""></a></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_12.jpg" width="6" height="49" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/i.school" target="_blank"><img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_13.jpg" width="34" height="35" alt=""></a></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_14.jpg" width="8" height="49" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/i/" target="_blank"><img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_15.jpg" width="34" height="35" alt=""></a></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_16.jpg" width="7" height="49" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/I" target="_blank"><img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_17.jpg" width="33" height="35" alt=""></a></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_18.jpg" width="7" height="49" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/is-6a235aa9" target="_blank"><img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_19.jpg" width="34" height="35" alt=""></a></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_20.jpg" width="21" height="49"   alt=""></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_21.jpg" width="34" height="14" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_22.jpg" width="34" height="14" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_23.jpg" width="34" height="14" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_24.jpg" width="33" height="14" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_25.jpg" width="34" height="14" alt=""></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="51" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="405" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="26" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="34" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="6" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="34" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="8" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="34" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="7" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="33" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="7" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="4" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="30" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="21" height="1" alt=""></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   <!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
   </body>
   </html>
```

Then this is the folder

```
  images
    index.html
```

Comment: give the image root link

Answer (score 1):

The images need to be hosted on a server and referenced absolutely in the emails html.

Eg: `http://your-domain-name/images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_08.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

this is work in your website because automatically take the root path in in mail not taken the root path

```
<img src="images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_03.jpg" width="51" height="123" alt="">
```

use like this

```
<img src="http://website.com/images/Eblast-WAE-Preorder_03.jpg" width="51" height="123" alt="">
```

Answer (score 1):

there are two thing in your code

1. please give you img tag absolute path . as like this `http://www.zymz.com/rohit.jpg`
2. is your a tag is inline it's define to inline-block as like this

```html
<a style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;" href="xyz.xcom"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

If not have online hosting means just upload the image in the Google Drive and make them file permission public and copy the folder id like OLKJGUIUIV5324654eswrw. now use this http://googledrive.com/host/OLKJGUIUIV5324654eswrw/imagename.png and send your email